# Forcing applications and dialogs to open to the active monitor

Tags: windows-7, display

I have two monitors, 24" and 13" (laptop's, primary). I already use [DisplayFusion](http://www.displayfusion.com) and [VistaSwitcher](http://www.ntwind.com/software/vistaswitcher.html) to ease the burden of this setup.

At the moment things work like this: whenever I open an application, it opens into the monitor it was positioned the last time. For some cases that's okay, and if the monitor is a wrong one, it doesn't take a second to pull the window from one monitor to another. Also, at least DisplayFusion lets me create rules for programs, if I like to.

But, not only am I not a huge fan of configuring every single software I'm about to use, but also there are numerous softwares which have many dialogs: to name one, GIMP (think about Filters). Also file save/open dialogs often go to the wrong monitor, forcing me to pause for a moment to realize what's going on.

That leads me to the question. Is there a software for or a build-in way in Windows 7 to force applications and dialogs to open to the active monitor - either the one that has the active window or the one mouse cursor is on? It doesn't matter if that's an option.

So far I haven't found a similar question from SO nor here. Even Google is powerless. Maybe this is impossible or useless feature or I'm just using wrong keywords, but hopefully someone is able to figure it out for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought about this myself and didn't come to a proper conclusion.

Are you sure you're really able to fully define a set of rules for new windows placement that would solve all your problems?

I doubt it.

I imagine stuff like a fullscreen video and my mouse cursor is on the screen with the video. Now all interesting windows open behind the fullscreen video.
Ok, so you need an exception for that. What about other *always on top* Windows?

There are numerous cases where you'll just be frustrated yet again.

So I, personally, settled for the ability to quickly change the position of a window.
Usually <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> work just fine for me.

I also used [UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/tour/windows.asp) in the past to achieve the same thing by mouse only.

Comment: You're making two solid points here with both setting rules for every single window and about actions when having something on full screen. However, although this is probably just the use case **I'm** having, those are both minimal issues: I mostly use some ten softwares and I hardly ever need full screen mode. But since that's just me, and Windows' shortcuts work as you said most of the time, I'm happy to accept your answer. Thank you!

Comment: @sankari I understand. Sorry that I couldn't offer a proper solution :(

Comment: No worries, I'm glad you tried!